Continuously compounding interest with continuous repayment

A person borrows Rs $640000$ at a nominal interest rate of $10\%$ per annum, compounded continuously. The borrower makes payments continuously at a constant rate of Rs $k$ per year such that the loan is paid off in exactly $3$ years. Determine $k,$ and the total interest paid.

I am not sure but I think, if the borrower is supposed to pay back the interest in 3 years then the final amount to be paid back in three years is calculated and then he can pay that same amount over time. Or will the fact that he pays continously as well affect the interest too? Here is how I solved the exercise; is it correct?
Principal amount $P = \text{Rs.} 640,000$, rate of interest is $r = 10\%$ per year, and time is $t = 3$ years. If $n$ is the number of times that the interest is compounded in one time period, which is $1$ year in this case, then the total amount to be paid is $$A = P\left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}$$
If interest is compounded continuously, then we can say that $n \to \infty$, so,
$$A = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(1 + \frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}$$
$$\implies A =  P\cdot e^{rt}$$
And if the constant annual payment rate is $k$ and the loan is to be paid back in 3 years, then we must have,
$$P\cdot e^{rt} = kt$$
$$\implies k = \frac{P\cdot e^{rt}}{t}$$
$$\implies k = \frac{\text{Rs.} \ 640,000\cdot e^{0.1 \times 3}}{3\ \text{years}}$$
$$\implies k \approx \text{Rs.}\ 287969.879 \ \text{per year}$$
And the net interest to be paid is $A - P = P(e^{0.3} - 1) \approx \text{Rs.}\ 223909.637$



A person borrows $\$640000$ at a nominal interest rate of $10\%$ per annum, compounded continuously. The borrower makes payments continuously at a constant rate of $\$k$ per year such that the loan is paid off in exactly $3$ years. Determine $k,$ and the total interest paid.


Let $\$L$ be the loan balance at time $t$ years. Then, noting that the annual change in loan balance equals the annual interest less the annual repayment,
$$\frac{\mathrm dL}{\mathrm dt}=0.1L-k,\\
L_{t=0}=640000,\\
L_{t=3}=0.$$
Solving this gives $L=10k+(640000-10k)e^{0.1t},$ and finally $$k=246,930.94.$$
The total interest paid is thus $\$(3k-640000)=\$100,792.82.$

I think, the total amount to be paid is $$A =  P e^{rt}= 640000  e^{0.1\times3},$$ so the total interest to be paid is $\$223,909.64.$

No, you are computing the total amount repaid if our borrower does so only at the end of $3$ years. Our actual total amount repaid is smaller, because our loan accrues less interest than $\$223,909.64$ due to being (partially) repaid throughout the $3$ years.

Ah, I understand now. I just wanted to ask you if you could tell me how did you arrive at the equation $dL/dt = 0.1L - k$? I can't quite figure it out

@A.Srivastava I've expanded the answer.
